# formula field to display images when the status of the picklist is changed

Tags: formula-field

```
IMAGE(
  IF(ISPICKVAL(Flat_Status__c, "Booked"), "img/msg_icons/confirm32.png",
      IF(ISPICKVAL(Flat_Status__c, "Sold"), "img/msg_icons/error32.png",
          IF(ISPICKVAL(Flat_Status__c, "Non-Serviced"), "img/msg_icons/warning32.png"),
              IF(etc....))
)
)
```

i get an error as -

> **Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2**

Any Help or suggestion would be Highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error, `IF` function expects 3 parameters

> IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)

1. Condition to evaluate i.e. logical test.
2. What should be the value if the condition evaluates to true.
3. What should be the value if the condition evaluates to false.

In your above formula, you did not mention what should happen when it does not match any of the mentioned statuses. Also you have not closed your `IFs` braces properly. I updated the `else` condition in your below formula to dummy image, you can replace it with the one which you want to display.

```
IMAGE(
    IF(ISPICKVAL(Flat_Status__c, "Booked"), "img/msg_icons/confirm32.png",
        IF(ISPICKVAL(Flat_Status__c, "Sold"), "img/msg_icons/error32.png",
        IF(ISPICKVAL(Flat_Status__c, "Non-Serviced"), "img/msg_icons/warning32.png",
        IF(etc...., "img/msg_icons/falseconditonimage.png"))))
)
```

Instead of using `IF` function, you can use `CASE` function here which is much simpler to understand and maintain.

Excerpt from [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) salesforce help link

> Use CASE functions to determine if a picklist value is equal to a
>   particular value.

Using `CASE` function, your formula would be

```
IMAGE(
    CASE(Flat_Status__c, 
    "Booked", "img/msg_icons/confirm32.png",
    "Sold", "img/msg_icons/error32.png",
    "Non-Serviced", "img/msg_icons/warning32.png",
    "etc", "img/msg_icons/warning33.png",
    "img/msg_icons/falseconditonimage.png")
)
```

You can find the documentation for using `CASE` function with picklist field at [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas/picklist_formulas) link.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the Link Mr Vijay, it solved my problem:)